# Project architecture in zend frame work

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am planning a new social networking project in zend frame work.

We have 3 types of user

- registered users
- admin users
- guests

Users can register, login, view events, view other user's profile, add them as a friend etc
Admin users manage user accounts, view events etc.

Which modules should I create for this project?

First I thought of making 2 modules admin and default.
Then I thought we can have event module, friends module etc but it make no sense. 
So how can I proceed  with this. I am not getting an idea. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Modules are the set of functional units. To decide the number of modules, we need to look into detailed functionality we need to provide and then categorize those into the modules.

Better keep the design loosely coupled so that you can refactor your design in future too if more functionalities are added and you think that a new module should be created.
Keep the shared resources (such as a database or a set of web services) and services( to provide system-wide services, such as authentication, logging, or configuration) in separate layers.

It will be easier for you to develop, test, deploy, and extend your application.

Feel free to ask any further questions. Thanks.

Comment: OK I have lot more to ask !